# ESAPI OWASP Client-Side session using cookies

Tags: java, session, authentication, owasp, esapi

I'm actually improving the authentication system of an existing app (JAVA+JAX-WS+Hibernate+GWT). I found the [OWASP Enterprise Security API Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API) and I liked it (except for the documentation). My application needs to be scalable and it requires to balance load between multiple web servers. To be able to do this, I'm thinking of using a signed cookie with session information, instead of using the usual server side approach. I've been looking the [source code and examples](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/FileBasedAuthenticator.java), but all of them take a server-side session approach.

**The question is then, ¿is there something within the ESAPI project to implement this signed cookie mechanism to handle sessions? The idea to use this project is not to reinvent the wheel, but I can build everything if necessary.**

If there isn't something useful in ESAPI, are there any similar java security projects that you recommend.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would actually recommend not to use esapi-auth for handling this.  I would recommend a project like spring security, or HDIV.  ESAPI 2.0 is near end of life.

Comment: Also, just to make sure, your language sounds like you have a problem with the session being managed on the server.  In web applications, the server is the *only* trusted component as far as a developer is concerned.  The client is a browser, and is patently out of your ability to control.

Comment: Ok thanks for the recommendation, I came to the same conclusion when I saw that there were no commits over the last year!! I don't plan to actually store much information in the cookie, just a user identifier that I can then use to retrieve the info on the server side.